# Copy files from amazon s3 bucket to a docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

```
Given that I have a s3 bucket called "mybucket"
And I have a docker container called "myfileserver"
And I have another docker container called "s3cli" with s3 cli commands
And I am on "s3cli" 
when I try to copy files from "mybucket" to "myfileserver"
Then I get confused how to do so?
```

What would be the best approach to copy files from mybucket to myfileserver when running command from s3cli container?

I've thought about using a datavolume shared between the containers? is there anything simpler or better?

Comment: A shared data volume would be definitely my preferred way to access mutual files from two or more containers. Even if one of them is only "serving"/creating them. It's easy and convenient.